# How to memorize the order of parameters to `ln` command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ln

I don't use `ln` command on daily basis, so when I need to create a link to a file, I always forget whether it's `ln <target file> <link name>`, or `ln <link name> <target file>`, so I have to take a quick glance at `man ln`.

As `ln` is commonly used in the process of software development, having the order firmly in memory would tremendously boost productivity.

Do you have any tricks (mnemonic?) for remembering the order of `ln` parameters?

Comment: If you hesitate, type `ln --help` ...

Comment: I was finally able to learn it after I remembered that the last part of second argument is the one that you have to _make up_ - it does not exists before. Like this, when making non-version link to newest Netbeans version: `ln -s $HOME/install/netbeans/netbeans8.0.2 $HOME/install/netbeans/netbeans`

Answer (score 35):

It takes arguments in the same order as `cp` and `mv`.

Comment: `cp <existing-thing> <new-thing>`  
   `mv <existing-thing> <new-thing>`        
    `ln <existing-thing> <new-thing>`

Comment: I think of it as `cp <from> <to>`, `mv <from> <to>` and `ln <from> <to>`

Comment: I think the reason <existing> <new> is better than <from> <to> is that the latter has the ambiguity that once the link exists, if it's a symbolic link, it takes you to the from.